# How To display Shipping cost in Total cart and tax?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shopping-cart

i want to show shipping in total cart,,,
This is screenshoot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should have `estimate shipping` block there to check the available `shipping method`, Then there you can choose & Your shipping rate will be include in Total after you will choose.